# Is there a way to get index fragmentation without using dm_db_index_physical_stats?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, fragmentation

I am using SQL Server 2016 SP1 standard edition.

The view dm_db_index_physical_stats is very slow on big databases. Even if I specify the 'LIMITED' option.

I use the view to get index fragmentation, to determine if I should do a REBUILD or a REORG in my maintenance. But as the databases grows, the call to the DMV dm_db_index_physical_stats takes more and more time. On some database, which can be as big as 1TB, it can take an hour to query the DMV. (I have no down time, there is always clients connected to the database doing work.)

So I was wondering if there's a way to know index fragmentation without querying the DMV.

Comment: I believe you are running it for whole database can you make it for table or a index, yes it can be slow for big databases see my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76374/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-is-extremly-slow/76378#76378)

Comment: I need to run it for the whole database. I need to know every index in the database and then choose which ones to REBUILD or REORG. I'm doing the whole database maintenance. Not only a single table.. I already know it can be slow for a big database. That's why I wanted to know if there's another way to get index fragmentation.

Comment: Or else what would you do? Question sys.indexes to know every object and index in the database, and then do an dm_db_index_physical_stats for every single object one at a time?

Comment: Usually if I can't fit everything into a maintenance window, I'll split the indexes out and do half in one window and half in another.

Comment: Yeah I already split the indexes over one week. What I'm trying to do is reduce the time it takes me to get the index fragmentation because I have 107 databases on this server, of different size, and I'm loosing a lot of time just to get the information from dm_db_index_physical_stats dmv

Comment: Have you considered restoring a copy of the database somewhere else and running the fragmentation stats against that? It is a little more work, but you could automate the restore and frag stats gathering which would allow you to focus on the individual indexes that need the attention.

Comment: @Nic: Have you considered posting an answer? :)

Comment: @AndriyM lol nah

Comment: Thanks @Nic I didn't think about that option. I guess I'll have to either do that or just keep the query as it is right now. Maybe I'll go and see if some indexes are not used and can be deleted or something.

Comment: I know this post is 3 years old but... it just doesn't matter how long it takes for sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats to execute because it's a totally online operation and does not need to be done during any down time.  Once you do it, you'll know how long it takes and you can schedule it to run and save it's output to a "DBA Utility Table" for use during the down time you have for actual index maintenance.  I'll also state that REORGANIZE doesn't do what most people think it does and should only be used for LOB compresssion and then only if needed an so you should stop routinely using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just resume the great suggestions that were made in the comments section :
The short answer is No, you have to use the DMV.

One possible alternative to using the DMV on the whole database would be to do it by table, but I need to do it for the whole database, and I already split index maintenance on multiple days so that it fits as much as possible in the maintenance window.

Another alternative would be to restore the database on another server and gather the index fragmentation over there.

I can also try to see if there's some unused indexes and see if I can remove some. I've found this query very use full, if it can serve someone else.
If you see indexes with no reads and only writes, it means that the index is only used when you insert rows in the table, but never in the SELECT queries. You can then analyse and decide if it's usefull and should be kept.

```
SELECT  '[' + DB_NAME() + '].[' + su.[name] + '].[' + o.[name] + ']' AS [statement] ,
        i.[name] AS [index_name] ,
        ddius.[user_seeks] + ddius.[user_scans] + ddius.[user_lookups]
            AS [user_reads] ,
        ddius.[user_updates] AS [user_writes] ,
        ddios.[leaf_insert_count] ,
        ddios.[leaf_delete_count] ,
        ddios.[leaf_update_count] ,
        ddios.[nonleaf_insert_count] ,
        ddios.[nonleaf_delete_count] ,
        ddios.[nonleaf_update_count]
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ddius
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON ddius.[object_id] = i.[object_id] AND i.[index_id] = ddius.[index_id]
INNER JOIN sys.partitions SP ON ddius.[object_id] = SP.[object_id] AND SP.[index_id] = ddius.[index_id]
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON ddius.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.sysusers su ON o.[schema_id] = su.[UID]
INNER JOIN sys.[dm_db_index_operational_stats](DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL) AS ddios
  ON ddius.[index_id] = ddios.[index_id]
  AND ddius.[object_id] = ddios.[object_id]
  AND SP.[partition_number] = ddios.[partition_number]
  AND ddius.[database_id] = ddios.[database_id]
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(ddius.[object_id], 'IsUserTable') = 1
      AND ddius.[index_id] > 0
      AND ddius.[user_seeks] + ddius.[user_scans] + ddius.[user_lookups] = 0
ORDER BY ddius.[user_updates] DESC ,
        su.[name] ,
        o.[name] ,
        i.[name ]
```